# Just need direction, classes or parameters in Powershell

Tags: powershell, class, active-directory

first post here and to be honest I'm a little gun shy. Last time I reached out was on technet and my work ethic, credibility, and abilities were all called into question when asking for direction. My hope is here, people will take it a little easier. If this question is in poor taste, just ask me to move along and i will.

Diatribe, over.

Ok, so what I am trying to accomplish is a simple powershell script that asks for a computername and based on the computer names prefix the script will add the computer object to specified security groups and move it to the proper OU.

I have the basic structure of it already working but I have to hard code the security groups and OU every time. My network has 35 sites, so I'm thinking i want the following info for each site.

```
$sitename
$sitesecuritygroups
$siteOU
```

I'm thinking this in class form:

```
Class Sites
  {
   [int]$sitenumber
   [string]$sitename `(ie. bronx)`
   [string]$sitesecuritygroup1 `(ie. all computers)`
   [string]$sitesecuritygroup2 `(ie. manager computers)`
   [String]$siteOU `(ie. ou=northeast,OU=Site Computers,OU=Computers,DC=contoso,DC=local)`
   [string]$sitecomputertype `(ie. Manager or Supervisor)
  }
```

So say i run the script it asks for a pc name, (ie. bronx01) and it looks at the input and figures out, ok this is a bronx pc, it needs added to the following security groups ($sitesecuritygroup1, $sitesecuritygroup2) and then move the object to this OU (Northeast Computers).

I realize i can put this info in a file and import it each time but I want to learn how to do it different. I would like this info to be able to be called without having to import anything. Basically persistent data through PS Sessions. I have looked into classes, and parameters but the deeper i get into each I'm not sure i can accomplish what i want.

So i say all that to simply ask, is what i want possible or worth it? And do you recommend classes or parameters? Again, i am not asking for someone to send me the code on how to do this, I'll figure that out, I just need to know if it's possible and whether to use classes or parameters.

Thank you in advance, I appreciate the time of anyone who looks into this.

UPDATE: Posting a comment won't let me ask my long question to your post Glen, here is my follow up question:

Thank you for responding so quickly. First question, I see your example has multiple site names in the variable. Should i not create a parameter set for each site, like this:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [int]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    $sitenumber(1)
    ,
    [string]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [ValidateSet('bronx')]
    $sitename
    ,
    [string]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    $sitesecuritygroup1
    ,
    [string]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    $sitesecuritygroup2
    ,
    [string]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [ValidateSet]('ou=northeast,OU=Site Computers,OU=Computers,DC=contoso,DC=local')
    $siteOU
    ,
    [string]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [ValidateSet('Manager')]
    $sitecomputertype
)


[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [int]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    $sitenumber(2)
    ,
    [string]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [ValidateSet('california')]
    $sitename
    ,
    [string]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    $sitesecuritygroup1
    ,
    [string]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    $sitesecuritygroup2
    ,
    [string]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [ValidateSet('ou=southwest,OU=Site Computers,OU=Computers,DC=contoso,DC=local')]
    $siteOU
    ,
    [string]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [ValidateSet('Manager')]
    $sitecomputertype
```

I like that you answered my question even though it doesn't appear how you would do it, but i'd like your opinion, is a JSON file the way to go? Am i trying to learn the wrong way to do something?

Comment: unless you have been using classes in other lingos ... don't start off with them in PoSh. even if you have, they are somewhat different even from c# classes in the various limitations ... so  i suspect you are likely better off using parameters. for your various lookups, i would use hashtables & save/load them via the `*-CliXml` cmdlets so that you get back fully structured objects. ///// if you REALLY want to get into complexity, take a look at dynamic parameters ... and then try not to run away screaming.  [*grin*]

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response, I will start researching this. I should have time tomorrow at work, so once I review it i may have some follow up questions.

Comment: you are very welcome! glad to kinda-sorta help ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is possible but is not a normal design pattern. 
Storing persistent data is an external JSON file or similar is a more mature pattern.
However that is not what you asked - so you can achieve what you want with mandatory parameters:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [int]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    $sitenumber
    ,
    [string]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [ValidateSet('Site1', 'Site2', 'Site3')]
    $sitename
    ,
    [string]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    $sitesecuritygroup1
    ,
    [string]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    $sitesecuritygroup2
    ,
    [string]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    $siteOU
    ,
    [string]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [ValidateSet('Manager', 'Supervisor')]
    $sitecomputertype
)
```